# Build expression tree for method decoration?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, dynamic-invoke

I’m building a class named `CommandHandler` that have `ExecuteCommand` method that have `Command` as input parameter.

The Idea is that `ExcecuteCommand` will check command name and execute proper class method by the name pattern so when command name is `Test` class should have corresponding `TestHandler` method.

On initialization I’m using reflection to find all methods and create a mapping between command name and created `Func<Command, Task<object>>`. For now I have achieve this by making all methods return `Task<object>` and use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to create `Func<Command, Task<object>>` from reflected method but I would like to clean code and allow methods to return simple types like int or `Task<custom class>`.

I would like to build some simple Expression that for simple types will execute method and do `Task.FromResult` dynamically so class method remains clean. For Task with specific type result I would like to create expression that will result `Task<object>` so all could be cached as `Dictionary<string, Func<Command, Task<object>>`.

```
 public class CommandHandler
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Func<Command, Task<object>>> methodCache = new Dictionary<string, Func<Command, Task<object>>>();

        public int IntCommandHandler(Command c)
        {
            return 5;
        }

        public string StringCommandHandler(Command c)
        {
            return "5";
        }

        public Task<int> AsyncIntCommandHandler(Command c)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => 5);
        }

        public async Task<object> OldWayCommandHandler(Command c)
        {
            return "5";
        }

        private void RegisterAsyncQueryHandlers(Dictionary<string, MethodInfo> handlers)
        {
            var filtered = handlers.Where(h => h.Value.ReturnType == typeof(Task<object>)).ToList();
            foreach (var handler in filtered)
            {
                methodCache.Add(handler.Key, (Func<Command, Task<object>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Command, Task<object>>), this, handler.Value, false));
            }
        }

        public void FillCache()
        {
            // Get all methods with proper pattern and pass it to RegisterAsyncQueryHandlers in dictionary of command name and MethodInfo
            //RegisterAsyncQueryHandlers
        }

        public Task<object> ExecuteCommand(Command c)
        {
            return methodCache[c.Name].Invoke(c);
        }
    }

    public class Command
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I have no experience with using Expressions and most of the samples I found are using basic operators and static methods. Maybe someone can help me ho w to build such expression?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need to use expression trees for this at all. Can't you write a method to accept the non-async function and return a task-returning delegate? For example `return value => Task.FromResult(func(value));`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the question is how to convert `Task<TResult>` to `Task<object>`.

It can be done for instance using the [`Task<TResult>.ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.continuewith?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_ContinueWith__1_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__0____0__) method as follows:

```
static Task<object> Convert<TResult>(Task<TResult> source)
{
    return source.ContinueWith(t => (object)t.Result);
}
```

It's possible to dynamically build such expression, but the easier would be to put the above method in your class and "call" it via the following [`Expression.Call`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Call_System_Type_System_String_System_Type___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression___) overload.

The method that builds expression and compiles a delegate from it could be like this:

```
Func<Command, Task<object>> MakeFunc(MethodInfo handler)
{
    var c = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Command), "c");
    var task = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(this), handler, c);
    if (task.Type != typeof(Task<object>))
        task = Expression.Call(GetType(), "Convert", new[] { task.Type.GetGenericArguments().Single() }, task);
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Command, Task<object>>>(task, c);
    return expr.Compile();
}
```